# Send along params with post call does not work

Tags: javascript, facebook

- Titanium SDK version: 1.6.1
- iPhone SDK version: 4.2

I have created a little snippet that posts to facebook on http://pastie.org/1744965. I am using it like this: http://pastie.org/1744971.

What I want to be able to do is to send the message params (or any param since I want to make it generic) to the snippet but it does not work. The feed get published but there is no message.

What can I do? What is wrong?

Comment: Just a thought here - have you tried *not* stringify-ing the `params` object?

Comment: Yes, tried with and without stringify. What I basically want is a way to add any params to the calling function and it will then work in the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your call to execute be sending an object as the parameter and not a string?

```
{"message" : "This is the message for the feed"}
```

and not

```
'{"message" : "This is the message for the feed"}'
```

Note the missing single quotes (`'`)

Comment: This might be the solution. But now the feed publish limit is reached for Facebook... So I cannot try it :)

Comment: No worries - try it out when you can and post back your results.

Comment: Tried another user with new limit and your solution worked fine! Thank you!

Comment: Great! I *was* going to suggest using a different user/API key to get around the limits :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good I would check the Facebook API to make sure you're sending the right format.

Comment: Thanks! It works if I in the calling file just add for example "testing a message" and in the snippet file enters "xhr.send({"message" :params});". But how can I send multiple params without this hardcoding?

Comment: Hmmm if "xhr.send({"message" :params});" is working then you may not need JSON.stringify try xhr.send(params);